# Cannot assign value to the SparsePandasDataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sparse-matrix

Cannot assign value to the SparsePandasDataframe, when I do the same with just PandasDataframe, it works fine. Can someone explain to me why?

```
data_ibs.iloc[0,2] = 10
```

> NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent
>   call last)
>        in ()
>       ----> 1 data_ibs.iloc[0,2] = 10
>
> ```
> /Users/ivanmac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
> ```
>
> in **setitem**(self, key, value)
>           177             key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
>           178         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
>       --> 179         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
>           180 
>           181     def _has_valid_type(self, k, axis):
>
> ```
> /Users/ivanmac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
> ```
>
> in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
>           586                 # scalar
>           587                 for item in labels:
>       --> 588                     setter(item, value)
>           589 
>           590         else:
>
> ```
> /Users/ivanmac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py
> ```
>
> in setter(item, v)
>           511                     s._consolidate_inplace()
>           512                     s = s.copy()
>       --> 513                     s._data = s._data.setitem(indexer=pi, value=v)
>           514                     s._maybe_update_cacher(clear=True)
>           515
>
> ```
> /Users/ivanmac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
> ```
>
> in setitem(self, **kwargs)
>          3201 
>          3202     def setitem(self, **kwargs):
>       -> 3203         return self.apply('setitem', **kwargs)
>          3204 
>          3205     def putmask(self, **kwargs):
>
> ```
> /Users/ivanmac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
> ```
>
> in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate,
>   **kwargs)
>          3089 
>          3090             kwargs['mgr'] = self
>       -> 3091             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
>          3092             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
>          3093
>
> ```
> /Users/ivanmac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
> ```
>
> in setitem(self, indexer, value, mgr)
>           688 
>           689         # cast the values to a type that can hold nan (if necessary)
>       --> 690         if not self._can_hold_element(value):
>           691             dtype, _ = maybe_promote(arr_value.dtype)
>           692             values = values.astype(dtype)
>
> ```
> /Users/ivanmac/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py
> ```
>
> in _can_hold_element(self, value)
>           547 
>           548     def _can_hold_element(self, value):
>       --> 549         raise NotImplementedError()
>           550 
>           551     def _try_cast(self, value):
>
> ```
> NotImplementedError:
> ```